Flutter ESC-POS Print Image fails after upgrade to 3.24.3
Before update, I was printing image like this:
final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('imageassets/logoassets/giblogo.png');
            if (data.lengthInBytes > 0) {
              final Uint8List imageBytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
              final decodedImage = decodeImage(imageBytes)!;
              Image thumbnail = copyResize(decodedImage, height: 150);
              Image originalImg = copyResize(decodedImage, width: 150, height: 150);
              fill(originalImg,color: ColorUint8.rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
              var padding = (originalImg.width - thumbnail.width) / 2;

              //drawImage(originalImg, thumbnail, dstX: padding.toInt());

              var grayscaleImage = grayscale(originalImg);
              bytes += generator.feed(1);
              bytes += generator.imageRaster(grayscaleImage, align: PosAlign.center,imageFn: PosImageFn.bitImageRaster);
              bytes += generator.feed(1);

It can clearly prints all images but after I updated to 3.24.3 it gives an exception error on imageRaster() function. Its header starts with:

Cannot add to a fixed-length list

Have you ever faced this problem. I would be happy if you help. Thanks in advance.
